# Function overloading: how to keep the same definition (body) and only change the parameters?

Tags: c++, overloading

I am making a Pacman game and I would like to write a Teleport() function, because my code for the teleporting feature is duplicated in my PacmanMovement() function and my GhostsMovement() function. I have a structure for Pacman, and a structure for the ghosts (array of 4). Both have identical variables (like "posX" and "posY") and some different ones (like "comportment" for ghosts). The problem is that the body of the teleport feature is exactly the same for both, except for the name of the structures, and since both are different structures, I can't just pass one structure in argument. I can overload the function, one with a structure of Pacman in parameter and the other one with a structure of ghosts, but I would have to duplicate my code for both function definitions, which is totally useless since I want to avoid duplicated code. I may also create a "character" structure to store both structures (Pacman and ghosts), but I prefer to keep them separated, because I have more control on them (for example if I want to declare new ghosts later) and my code is already really heavy. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what function templates are for.

Comment: That seems like a classic example of why you'd want inheritance.

Comment: I think you need to make you program object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the function a template, deducing the appropriate object type:

```
template <typename Agent>
void Teleport(Agent& agent, int x, int y) {
     agent.x = y;
     agent.y = y;
}
```

That said, I would expect the agents in a simple game to be objects deriving from a common base class which provides the common functionality and `virtual` functions for the custom functionality.